# Get the return value from mongoose call back function Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have written a function like this

```
function create(data, res){

    var history= new historyData({
        owner: data
    });

    historyData.save(function(err, historyData) {


        //To identify the error
        if (err) {


            console.log(err);
        }

        //If no error pass the team details to databsae
        else {

            return historyData.id;       

        }
    });
}
```

and I'm trying to get the return value like this

```
var history = create("saddsa", res);
```

but it gives `undefined` error

I want to get the `id` of the created collection and pass it to another function?

Comment: you can't return value from save method.

Comment: So how can i get the saved data id and pass to another function?? @AshishSuthar

Comment: you can give a callback function and get that data from there

Comment: Ok if you can give an example that will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return a `callback` and get that value

```
function create(data, res, callback) {

  var history = new historyData({
    owner: data
  });

  historyData.save(function(err, historyData) {
    //To identify the error
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      callback(err)
    }

    //If no error pass the team details to databsae
    else {
      return callback(null,historyData.id);

    }
  });
}
```

---

```
 // call your function like this    
  create("saddsa", res,function(err,result){
      if(!err){
        console.log(result)
      }
    });
```

Comment: are you getting value in `historyData.id` after saving?

Comment: yes i'm getting and in the callback functions result i'm getting the id but couldn't get it to a variable

Comment: check your `historyData.id` when return after saving? console.log(historyData.id)

Comment: it gives the id

Comment: i'm tryin to get the value like this `var history = create("saddsa", res,function(err,result){
      if(!err){
        console.log(result)
      }
    });`  it gives undefined error

Comment: It should work, if you get value in callback(null,historyData.id);

Comment: how to get the value from the callback function. i couldn't get the value from the callback function the result variable in the callback function has the id

Comment: If you do not get `error` and enter in `else condition` put `callback(null,historyData);`

And get that value like at calling time if `(!err){
console.log(historyData)//if you get right value then access historyData.id
}`

Answer (score 0):

replace

`return historyData.id;`

with

`if(res) res(historyData.id);`

and call

```
create("saddsa", function (id) { var history = id; });
```

Comment: It's not gonna work. Have you test it? Define proper callback with proper parameters(`err`,`value`)